# ¿Como puedo obtener todos los hijos de una categoria?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
public class AllCategory {

    int id;
    String nombre; 
    int padre;
    List<Clase> hijos;

}
```

Recibo una lista del siguiente objeto:

```
public class Category {

    int id;
    String nombre; 
    int padre;
    List<Clase> hijos;

}
```

Cada Category tiene un id, el nombre y el id de su category padre. Quiero obtener una lista de AllCategory de manera que cada nodo de la lista sea el padre y los sub nodos sus hijos, de verdad no se como hacerlo. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Ambas clases son iguales, y no está claro lo que preguntas, puedes ser más especifico, por ejemplo, poner valores y salidas prueba, para saber a qué quieres llegar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que manejes una sola clase

```
public class Category {

   int id;
   String nombre; 
   Integer padre; // Si el valor es nulo, entonces es padre
   List<Category> hijos;

}
```

Con esta clase entonces si el padre es nulo quiere decir que es el padre y que no tiene ningún antecesor.
En caso contrario todas las categorías dentro de hijos son sus hijos y vas guardando la relación del padre dentro del miembro padre.
Checa que el data type fue cambiando a Integer para permitir nulos a ese miembro, los primitivos(int, double,etc) no admiten nulos.